# ¿Cómo puedo seleccionar varias filas de un data grid, para después manipularlas en Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, wpf, mvvm, botón

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación en *C#* con un *data grid* que muestra datos de una base de datos, los cuales una de sus propiedades es la de nivel. Al presionar un botón, su propiedad de nivel cambia al siguiente, pero cambia la propiedad de todas las filas.

Necesito poder seleccionar el número de filas que yo quiera, y que al dar click en el botón, solo cambie la propiedad de las filas seleccionadas, sin afectar las otras, o una manera en que pueda controlar el número de filas que deseo modificar.

Al dar click en el botón, se ejecuta el siguiente método:

```
private void MoveTo()
{
    var nextStep = getNextStep(this.SelectedDeviceStep);

    var confirmResult = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(String.Format(Dico.ConfirmModeDevicesTo, nextStep.ToString()), Dico.Title, MessageBoxButton.YesNo); 
    //Pregunta si esas seguro de querer cambiar el nivel
    if (confirmResult == MessageBoxResult.No)
    {
        return;
    }
    using (var service = UnityFactory.Resolve<IBusinessService>())
    {
        foreach (var item in this.Devices)
        {
            if (item.Device != null)
            {
                service.SetDeviceStatus(item.Device.Id, nextStep);
            }
        }
    }
    MessageBoxShow(String.Format(Dico.DevicesMovedToSuccess, nextStep.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: La aplicación es Winforms?

Comment: No, es aplicacion WPF

Comment: Has intentado hace un bucle `foreach(DataRowView dgvr in dg.SelectedItems) { }`?

Comment: Si `Devices`es tu DataGrid, como te he dicho el bucle deberia ser `foreach (var item in this.Devices.SelectedItems)...`

Comment: Ese es el problema, no existe Device.SelectedItems

Comment: `Device` no,`Devices`. Siempre que `Devices` sea un WPF Datagrid. Es asi?

Comment: Devices es una propiedad, que almacena datos de los diferentes dispositivos que trabajo, y todo ese metodo esta dentro de un ViewModel.cs con el que trabaja el wpf, por medio de una serie otros metodos y llamadas hace la union entre el ViewModel y el WPF, por lo tanto no puedo accesar directamente los metodos y propiedades del data grid en el metodo que quiero

Comment: Ok,empezamos a entendernos. Estas usando MVVM. Efectivamente, no se puede hacer un binding de `SelectedItems` al viewmodel. [Aqui(en ingles)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880589/bind-to-selecteditems-from-datagrid-or-listbox-in-mvvm) puedes ver algunas soluciones

Answer (score 0):

Si es lo que yo entiendo y una fila es un "device" la solución es muy sencilla, pon atención:

Carga el DataGrid usando como ItemsSource una lista de objetos, no lo cargues usando un DataTable, DataView o DataSet, usa una lista, algo así:

```
List<Device> mydevices = new List<Device>();
mydevices.Add(new Device("Device1", new Nivel(1)));
mydevices.Add(new Device("Device2", new Nivel(4)));
...
```

Y esa lista la asignas como ItemsSource

```
Devices.ItemsSource = mydevices;
```

En el botón que subirá el nivel crea una lista del mismo tipo y la llenas asi:

```
List<Device> selectedDevices = new List<Device>();
foreach (Device d in Devices.SelectedItems)
{
    selectedDevices.Add(d);
}
```

Si lo tienes con MVVM es mucho más fácil aún ya que el SelectedItems lo puedes Bindear..

Luego con un foreach le subes el nivel a todo lo que estaba seleccionado, puedes ponerlo directamente debajo del código anterior:

```
foreach (Device d in selectedDevices)
{
    d.AumentarNivel();
}
```

O puedes hacer todo más rápido sin crear ninguna lista temporal sino hacer el foreach y aplicar el aumento de nivel directamente por cada item..

Un saludo.